# find the control by type

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular-ui-grid

I have Angular ui-grid in one of the columns I have used cell template the code is given below

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"  > <input name="files" id="files" type="file" /></div>'
```

I want to find the input control of type file through jquery code given below

```
var k = $("input[type='file']");
```

But this is not working it cannot find the control inside grid but if the control is placed outside grid the above code finds it any idea how to find any control inside the grid.

Comment: Your code should work. Can you provide SO Snippet with issue?

Comment: Hi what Is SO I think the code is not working because the code executes before the grid is rendered any idea how to know when angular ui-grid redered is complete

Comment: `SO Snippet` is fifth icon in editor window (next to image, icon with `<>`). Try looking for callback elements.